# Different results when computing linear regressions with scipy.stats and statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, statsmodels

I'm getting different values of r^2 (coefficient of determination) when I try OLS fits with these two libraries and I can't quite figure out why. (Some spacing removed for your convenience)

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd       
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: import statsmodels.api as sm
In [4]: import scipy.stats
In [5]: np.random.seed(100)
In [6]: x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100) + 5*np.random.randn(100)
In [7]: y = np.arange(100)

In [8]: slope, intercept, r, p, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)

In [9]: r**2
Out[9]: 0.22045988449873671

In [10]: model = sm.OLS(y, x)
In [11]: est = model.fit()

In [12]: est.rsquared
Out[12]: 0.5327910685035413
```

What is going on here? I can't figure it out! Is there an error somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0.2205 is coming from a model which *also* has an intercept term--the 0.5328 value is the result if you remove the intercept.

Basically, one package is modeling **y = bx** whereas the other (helpfully) assumes that you would *also* like an intercept term (i.e. **y = a + bx**). [Note: The advantage of this assumption is that otherwise you would have to take **x** and bind a column of ones to it every time you wanted to run a regression (or else you'd end up with a *biased* model)]

Check out [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36064/calculating-r-squared-coefficient-of-determination-with-centered-vs-un-center) for a longer discussion.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh that makes sense! (But wait - are you sure the 0.2205 is the model with the intercept term? I was thinking that since a higher r^2 means closer correlation, then more flexibility implies higher correlation hence higher r^2 - is that correct?)

Comment: Yeah, I ran it in **R** to double-check.

Comment: Do you know the reason then of why my intuition is wrong?

Comment: Also, part of the problem is that you're kind of using a crazy model. Try simplifying things a bit (i.e. something like `x = np.random.randn(100)` and then `y = 4 + 11*x` and *then* try running the regression--that way you'll know to look for (i.e. an intercept=4, slope=11))

Comment: Yep - thanks! I had just been doing stuff like y = np.sin(x)**2 or that type of thing, but I didn't really even think to add an intercept. It would have taken me forever to find this!

Comment: Yeah, it gets confusing, especially since some packages automatically add the intercept while others don't (apparently).

Comment: James: Try calculating the Correlation the usual way (i.e. **cov(x,y)/(sd(x)sd(y))**)--the result (about 0.47) is consistent with the R^2 term from the regression with the intercept (since 0.47^2 is about 0.22). The reason is that the sqrt(R**2) is only equal to the correlation coefficient when you're dealing with an OLS regression (i.e. *with* an intercept). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-squared#As_squared_correlation_coefficient)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to the original question which has been answered.

About R-squared in a regression without a constant.

One problem is that a regression without an intercept doesn't have the standard definition of R^2.

Essentially, R-squared as a goodness of fit measure in a model with an intercept compares the full model with the model that has only an intercept. If the full model does not have an intercept, then the standard definition of R^2 can produce weird results like negative R^2.

The conventional definition in the regression without constant divides by the total sum of squares of the dependent variable instead of the demeaned. The R^2 between a regression with a constant and without cannot really be compared in a meaningful way.

see for example the issue that triggered the change in statsmodels to handle R^2 "correctly" in the no-constant regression: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/785

Comment: This links expands on the typical formula in each case: tss = (ys ** 2).sum()  # un-centred total sum of squares
tss = ((ys - ys.mean())**2).sum()  # centred total sum of squares http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851787/statsmodels-calculate-fitted-values-and-r-squared/24852415#24852415