# Statsmodels: Calculate fitted values and R squared

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I am running a regression as follows (`df` is a `pandas` dataframe):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
est = sm.OLS(df['p'], df[['e', 'varA', 'meanM', 'varM', 'covAM']]).fit()
est.summary()
```

Which gave me, among others, an R-squared of `0.942`. So then I wanted to plot the original `y-values` and the fitted values. For this, I sorted the original values:

```
orig = df['p'].values
fitted = est.fittedvalues.values
args = np.argsort(orig)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(orig[args], 'bo')
plt.plot(orig[args]-resid[args], 'ro')
plt.show()
```

This, however, gave me a graph where the values were completely off. Nothing that would suggest an R-squared of `0.9`. Therefore, I tried to calculate it manually myself:

```
yBar = df['p'].mean()
SSTot = df['p'].apply(lambda x: (x-yBar)**2).sum()
SSReg = ((est.fittedvalues - yBar)**2).sum()  
1 - SSReg/SSTot
Out[79]: 0.2618159806908984
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a reason why my computation is so far off what statsmodels is getting? `SSTot`, `SSReg` have values of `48084`, `35495`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you do not include an intercept (constant explanatory variable) in your model, statsmodels computes R-squared based on *un-centred* total sum of squares, ie.

```
tss = (ys ** 2).sum()  # un-centred total sum of squares
```

as opposed to

```
tss = ((ys - ys.mean())**2).sum()  # centred total sum of squares
```

as a result, R-squared would be much higher.

This is mathematically *correct*. Because, R-squared should indicate how much of the variation is explained by the full-model comparing to the reduced model. If you define your model as:

```
ys = beta1 . xs + beta0 + noise
```

then the reduced model can be: `ys = beta0 + noise`, where the estimate for `beta0` is the sample average, thus we have: `noise = ys - ys.mean()`. That is where *de-meaning* comes from in a model with intercept.

But from a model like:

```
ys = beta . xs + noise
```

you may only reduce to: `ys = noise`. Since `noise` is assumed zero-mean, you may not de-mean `ys`. Therefore, unexplained variation in the reduced model is the *un-centred* total sum of squares.

This is documented [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html?highlight=rsquared) under `rsquared` item. Set `yBar` equal to zero, and I would expect you will get the same number.

Comment: In some cases, OLS uses centered model, I don't understand why. Didn't tell, that is centered. Can you check the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/510040/statsmodels-ols-r2-calculation?noredirect=1#comment941381_510040)

Answer (score 5):

If your model is:

```
a = <yourmodel>.fit()
```

Then, to compute fitted values:

```
a.fittedvalues
```

and to compute R squared:

```
a.rsquared
```